# How To Test SSL On Development Server Without SSL Certificate

Tags: magento-1.9, https, base-url, secure

I'm testing some code that changes a link to use the secure base URL, but my development server does not have an SSL certificate. I'm trying to fake it and have so far been unsuccessful.

I have links that use https on my live site, which are using http on the development site. I'm assuming that these will change with the secure base URL (which is currently set to http).

I've tried simply setting the secure base URL to https, but this crashes the admin (easily fixed by changing it back in core_config_data and deleting var/cache) and doesn't change the links that I already know use the secure URL on the live site.

I'm not sure what else to try, short of actually going and purchasing the cheapest SSL certificate I can find for use on my development server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your development server can be reached publicly, you can use the [free certificate authority LetsEncrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org), otherwise your best option is probably to just [generate a self-signed certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04). Your browser may complain about that cert initially, but most allow you to add it to your trusted list so that you no longer get security warnings.